# Eager loading nested entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following (kept really simple):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public IEnumerable<Reminder> Reminders {get; set}
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders {get; set}
}

public class Reminder
{
    public int CustomerId {get; set}
    public string Text {get; set}
}

public class Order
{
    public int CustomerId {get; set}
    public int CategoryId {get; set}
}

public class OrderDetails
{
    public int OrderId {get; set}
    public int ProductId {get; set}
}
```

I'm also using generic repository pattern, and I load entities with nested entities as follows:

```
    public virtual T Get(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
    {
        if (include.Any())
        {
            var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                        (dbset, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

            return set.SingleOrDefault<T>(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        return dbset.Find(id);
    }
```

Using Linq, I would like to load a Customer, all his Reminders and all Orders (and their details) having a particular CategoryId. So I'm trying to do like this:

```
var customer = customerRepository.Get(10, x => x.Reminders, x => x.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderDetails));
```

But the above loads everything. And if I do the following, an exception is thrown:

```
var customer = customerRepository.Get(10, x => x.Reminders, x => x.Orders.Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId).Select(o => o.OrderDetials));
```

So how can I actually return only those orders I need?

Comment: I am prety sure you can't do this with EF at the moment. From MSDN "Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always being in all related entities." source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232

Comment: How can I retrieve only those Orders I need after loading the customer because once the customer is retrieved, the Orders collection is null.